# How do I change a char using toUpperCase() in Java

Tags: java, char, boolean, boolean-logic

### The user must only input a char and has to be changed to uppercase then checked if it equals E, T, or M.

I've tried doing initializing rating to another variable then using that variable but I receive an error message that toUpperCase() must be on a String, I've also tried equalsIgnoreCase() and using that variable with toUpperCase().

```
public boolean setRating(char rating)
    {
        boolean valid = true;
        if(rating.toUpperCase('e') || rating.toUpperCase('t') || rating.toUpperCase('m'))
        {
        this.rating = rating;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `java.lang.Character`, there's a method called `toUpperCase`, that's the best way to get a char in upper case.

You could use: `Character.toUpperCase(rating) == 'E'`...